# Flashbuilder VideoDisplay error

Tags: android, flash-builder

I am currently building an app using Flashbuilder for an Android device.

On several pages I have a spark component videodisplay or videoplayer in the pages.

For whatever reason the first time I open the app and navigate to that page the video doesn't load.
If I move off that page and go back the video shows fine.
If I then lock the screen, and then go back to the app I again navigate to a page with a video and again it doesn't display on that first showing.

Extensive websearch etc and I cannot find anybody else with the same error.

trace() shows video loads fine, both in s:videodisplay and s:videoplayer.

Any help would be brilliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem

It would appear that this is actually a bug with the AIR SDK (Bug 3354849 on Adobe Bugbase refers)

The new version of SDK (3.7) now requires the following code added to the manifest file.

```
<containsVideo>true</containsVideo>
```